# Get radius from Vector size

Tags: p5.js

Using p5js a circle gets created:

```
EarthSize = createVector(width/3, height/3);
Eclipse(200, 200, EarthSize.x, EarthSize.y);
```

I want to get the size in radius of the circle.

off course I can use width/3 similar to what the vector is using but can I get this directly from the EarthSize vector?

Comment: What's `Eclipse` exactly? The vector here is just an x/y coordinate pair without a radius.

Comment: Given that the name of the variable is `EarthSize` and its usage, it seems like the `x` component is really the width of the ellipse and the `y` component is it's height

Comment: I suppose you mean `Ellipse` instead of `Eclipse`. If you have a circle, then `EarthSize.x` is the same as `EarthSize.y` which is the diameter of the circle. Radius will then just be any of this two values divided by 2.  If the two values are not the same, then you have an ellipse and it's not clear what you mean by radius.